# Using struts2 to redirect with dynamic parameters not working

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, parameters, struts2, action

I'm having an issue while trying to redirect mapping with dynamic parameters.

**The way I'm mapping in Struts2:**

```
<action name="Delete" class="templateLalaAction" method="remove">
    <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
        <param name="actionName">LalaTemplatesDisplay</param>
        <param name="buId">${buId}</param>
    </result>
    <result name="failure" type="redirect-action">
        LalaTemplatesDisplay
    </result>
</action>
```

**The method "remove" in the action:**

```
remove() {

    putRequestAttribute("buId",Long.valueOf("1111"));
    return SUCCESS;
}
```

if I do this, I'm setting the `buId=1111`, but when I run the app, the `url` ends with `buId=  (it's empty)`, i.e., no parameter is being passed. 
if I comment the `putRequestAttribute` method, and set struts passing `buId` parameter as a `static` value:

```
<action name="Delete" class="templateLalaAction" method="remove">
    <result name="success" type="redirect-action">
        <param name="actionName">LalaTemplatesDisplay</param>
        <param name="buId">1111</param>
    </result>
    <result name="failure" type="redirect-action">
        LalaTemplatesDisplay
    </result>
</action>
```

It works and the `url` ends with `buId=1111`.

I also read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784527/struts-2-parameters-between-actions) where the accepted answer teaches us to do the same I did, but if we read the comments the user did, we'll see he has the same problems I have. What am I possibly doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your method just assign `buId` variable and you need getter/setters for it in your action class.

```
public String remove() {
  buId = 1111l;
  return SUCCESS;
}
```

Also you are using old syntax for `redirect-action`, use camel case `redirectAction`.

Comment: I better not change because this code (redirect-action) is old, so i won't be able to refactor it all (unfortunatelly) :/