# How to pass parameters of type List between actions?

Tags: java, struts2

I have a form which has a single check box, users need to select some of the options and choose one of the provided buttons. Two of the buttons should return the selected options to the same action (First Action) that triggered the page and the other button needs to send the options to another action (Next Action).

As I could not define two separate forms for a single check box, currently I am redirecting all the buttons to the First Action and try to redirect to Next Action from there. Therefore I am using the param tag to pass the required variable but I cant access it in my second action.

Goal is to have three separate submit buttons for a single check box.

I have compared my code with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/784527/struts-2-parameters-between-actions), although they seem to be the same but mine does not work.

**Form**

```
   <form name="FirstActionFrom" method="POST" action="doActions">
             Check box goes here
      <input id="ThisBtn1" type="submit" name="req" value="This1"/>&nbsp
      <input id="ThisBtn2" type="submit" name="req" value="This2"/>
      <input id="NextBtn" type="submit" name="req" value="Next"/>
   </form>
```

**First Action:**

```
.....
private List<Long> selectedOptions;
{ 
    System.err.println("size of options:" + this.selectedOptions.size()); 
  if req is equal to Next then
      return "NextAction"
  else do whatever is required
}

 getter and setter go here
}
```

**Struts.xml**

```
 <result name="NextAction" type="redirectAction">
                <param name="actionName">NextAction</param>
                <param name="namespace">/Users/Next</param>
                <param name="selectedOptions">${selectedOptions}</param>
 </result>
```

**Next Action**

```
.....
private List<Long> selectedOptions;

... { 
  System.err.println("size of options:" + this.selectedOptions.size()); <<Always shows Zero
  return "showThis"
}

 getter and setter go here
}
```

**Result after selecting a single option**

```
SEVERE : size of options:1
SEVERE : size of options:0
```

Comment: does the second action have the correct public setter/getter for the parameter?

Comment: yes it does question is updated

Comment: Are you sure the the first action is collecting all parameters appropriately?

Comment: yes it shows the correct size

Comment: it seems you cant pass collections to the other action, need to use either session or a variable of type string. Have a look at the following answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506132/how-to-pass-a-list-from-one-action-to-another-in-struts-2-without-using-session

Comment: @J888 do you need to pass the values to two different action class..?? Is that what you looking for..? And in Struts..!!

Comment: @J888 On button click one you want to pass that to an Action ClassA and on 2nd button to an Action Class B..??

Comment: @Dileep yes each btn need to call different class

Comment: @j888 i have already posted the answer

Comment: @J888 Did you tried what i said..??

Comment: @Dileep yes but did not work

Comment: @j888 struts is actually setting values to the bean while mapping through the Controller. It will set all the component in the form submitted to the destination bean,if there is a component at the bean with same name and with getrs and setrs. Do u get the values in any one of ur bean..??

Answer (score -1, accepted):

it seems you cant pass collections as it is to the other action, need to use either session or a variable of type string. Have a look at the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16506132/how-to-pass-a-list-from-one-action-to-another-in-struts-2-without-using-session).

I recommend not to use session or type string variable, but call a method of the next action from your first action and once all the calculations are done, send redirect request to its other method to return its result page.

Comment: Its perfectly possible. In the link above, the problem is with the tags. Tags like textfield, select, hidden etc will pass the value to the class pointed by the struts. !! You cant pass the values if its using tags like s:property etc.!!

Answer (score -1):

It can be easily done by **changing the form action**,  in the JSP Page..

> You can use **JavaScript to change the action name**. By doing that you can map
> the jsp to another class using struts.XML. All you need is a new action definition in the **Struts.XMl.**
>
> In the bean class, you just
> want create a variable with the name of your list and of the same type, and finally
> create Getters and setters. You will be getting all the values in the
> jsp, (***irrespective of the type***) inside the bean(struts maps the values for you).

Since you have said that you already got the list in one action. I am not getting in to that part.

**Now here is how you can redirect the bean class(Action) from JSP.**

**Jsp File**

```
    <s:form id="formid" action="action1">
/.../
<s:hidden name="lstVariablename"/>
<s:hidden name="lstVariablename"/>
<s:hidden name="lstVariablename"/>
<s:hidden name="lstVariablename"/>
/.../
    </s:form>
```

Now create a JavaScript function inside the JSP

```
<script>    
function changeAction(){
    document.formid.action =action2
    }
</script>
```

**struts.XML**

```
  <action name="action1" 
        class="com.XXX.Action1" 
        method="methodOfAction1">
        <result name="success">/name.jsp</result>
  </action>

  <action name="action2" 
        class="com.XXX.Action2"  
        method="methodOfAction2">
        <result name="success">/name.jsp</result>
  </action>
```

Inside the Bean Class(Action)

```
private List<String> lstVariablename;

/....Getters and Setters............
```

Comment: I have been doing this for years and got a downvote for that..!! Pitty on you. If you don't understand what i have said, please ask first..!!